# Creating functions in objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

I came across the following recently, which seems to be an object declaration, starting with just a semi-colon. It works fine.

> ;(function() {
>     var ..... = this;
>   })()

Are there any difference in declaring it this way or if there are alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of concepts you've got wrong.

1. Though functions are objects too, this isn't a object declaration, it's a normal function declaration.
2. The functional form you've used is self-invoking function.
3. The semi-colon `;` is used so that the code doesn't break when several scripts are minified into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

"functions in objects" are called methods.

```
var foo = {
     x: function() {} // method
}
```